# Android layout inner view keep proportions for all devices

Tags: android, layout, positioning

I'm implementing this `Layout`:

[image]

It contains the `Background Image`, the `Phone Image` and the white `white view` inside the phone. That one would be a `gif animation`.

Here is my code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:background="@drawable/empty_background"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/iphone_background">


<pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
    android:id="@+id/inner_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="140dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="240dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

It looks fine in my `Nexus 5` on `Lollipop 5.0`, but the `Inner View` (gif) looks different for each resolution.

Any help would be great, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Hmm this requires bit calculations well you can use pixplicity.com and calculate different dp sizes for different size screens.

For ex:

if the original image size is 640*480 pixels for xhdpi then for others it wud be

length :

ldpi    @ 320.00dp  = 240.00px  = 320.00sp  = 50.80mm   = 2.00in    = 144.00pt

mdpi    @ 320.00dp  = 320.00px  = 320.00sp  = 50.80mm   = 2.00in    = 144.00pt

tvdpi   @ 320.00dp  = 426.00px  = 320.00sp  = 50.80mm   = 2.00in    = 144.00pt

hdpi    @ 320.00dp  = 480.00px  = 320.00sp  = 50.80mm   = 2.00in    = 144.00pt

xhdpi   @ 320.00dp  = 640.00px  = 320.00sp  = 50.80mm   = 2.00in    = 144.00pt

xxhdpi  @ 320.00dp  = 960.00px  = 320.00sp  = 50.80mm   = 2.00in    = 144.00pt

xxxhdpi @ 320.00dp  = 1280.00px = 320.00sp  = 50.80mm   = 2.00in    = 144.00pt

and breadth :

ldpi    @ 240.00dp  = 180.00px  = 240.00sp  = 38.10mm   = 1.50in    = 108.00pt

mdpi    @ 240.00dp  = 240.00px  = 240.00sp  = 38.10mm   = 1.50in    = 108.00pt

tvdpi   @ 240.00dp  = 319.50px  = 240.00sp  = 38.10mm   = 1.50in    = 108.00pt

hdpi    @ 240.00dp  = 360.00px  = 240.00sp  = 38.10mm   = 1.50in    = 108.00pt

xhdpi   @ 240.00dp  = 480.00px  = 240.00sp  = 38.10mm   = 1.50in    = 108.00pt

xxhdpi  @ 240.00dp  = 720.00px  = 240.00sp  = 38.10mm   = 1.50in    = 108.00pt

xxxhdpi @ 240.00dp  = 960.00px  = 240.00sp  = 38.10mm   = 1.50in    = 108.00pt

and u need to save gif name same for all different images and place them accordingly in respective drawable folders (mdpi,hdpi,xhdpi,xxhdpi).

Answer (score 0):

`Background Image` is OK to take `match_parent` dimensions.
But, for `Phone Image` and `GIF Image` try putting each in separate `LinearLayouts` stacked over one-another, and setting the `layout_width` to `0dp` and `layout_height` to `wrap_content` for both along with specifying the `layout_weight` to properly align the views, this can make your views look similar throughout all screens.